# Deserialize a field into 2 fields

Tags: rust, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a field "name" into "firstname" and "lastname".

My struct:

```rs
struct User {
    #[serde(rename = "name", deserialize_with = "deserialize_firstname")]
    firstname: String,

    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_lastname")]
    #[serde(rename = "name")]
    lastname: String,
    }
```

And the deserialize function is the following:

```rs
fn deserialize_firstname<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<String, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: &str = serde::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    let re = Regex::new(r"^\W*([\w-]+)").unwrap();
    let m = re.find(s);

    match m {
        Some(value) => Ok( value.as_str().to_string()),
        None => Ok("".to_string()),
    }
}
```

(it is about the same thing for lastname).

I get the following error:

```
 err: DeserializeError { field: None, kind: Message("missing field `name`") }
```

My question: How to deserialize a field into two different fields?

Comment: Why not make your own `Name` type that handles this? This also assumes you can reasonably determine a first/last name pair from an arbitrary string, which I doubt, as the rules here are extremely convoluted.

Comment: It is what I already did, I was wondering if it could be done during the deserialization. To determine the first/last name pair I made many regex rules and so far the results exceed my expectations ;)

Comment: I'd suggest making a `Name` concern, then, like `struct Name` which has the various components in it. Then you can implement your own serializer and deserializer for it. This does mean doing stuff like `user.name.first` instead of `user.first_name` but I think the clarity you get is worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serde can flatten structs, making the Rust representation more nested than the serialized representation, but it can't unflatten, which you're trying to do here. Instead, you can do that yourself by annotating the entire struct. Here we have `UserSerde` which reflects the serialized structure, and convert it to `User`, which is what you're looking for. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32d3c07829ebd398dc118a9eaeca5e64)

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct UserSerde {
    name: Name,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(try_from = "&str")]
struct Name {
    first: String,
    last: String,
}

impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a str> for Name {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: &'a str) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let re = regex::Regex::new(r"^\W*([\w-]+)\W+([\w-]+)\W*$").unwrap();
        let Some(caps) = re.captures(value) else {
            return Err("could not parse a first and last name");
        };
        Ok(Self {
            first: caps[1].to_string(),
            last: caps[2].to_string(),
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(from = "UserSerde")]
struct User {
    first: String,
    last: String,
    // other fields...
}

impl From<UserSerde> for User {
    fn from(value: UserSerde) -> Self {
        let UserSerde {
            name: Name { first, last },
        } = value;
        Self { first, last }
    }
}
```

Note that if you're using this to store arbitrary human names, splitting them into first and last names is [not a good idea](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/). At least have a fallback that's just a normal `String`.